# How to control the location of Windows Forms ContextMenu when it is shown by pressing the Menu key?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a custom Windows Forms Control to which I want to add a context menu. The custom control has an active selection that can be manipulated by keyboard or mouse. I set the custom control's `ContextMenu` property to the context menu I wish to show. When the user right-clicks, the context menu appears right where it is expected.

However, when the user presses the Menu key (or equivalently, `Shift-F10`) the context menu appears in the dead center of my control. I would like to be able to control the location of where the context menu appears depending on where the selection is in the control. How is this done? And does it also work for `ContextMenuStrip`?

**EDIT**

I'm writing up the worked solution given the answer below. First, set the `ContextMenu` property (or `ContextMenusStrip` property, as appropriate). Then, override the `OnKeyDown` method to intercept `Shift-F10`, and do an explicit `Show()` in that case.

```
this.ContextMenu = <my context menu>;

protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyData == (Keys.Shift|Keys.F10)) 
    {
        ContextMenu.Show(this, new Point(<x and y coordinates as appropriate>));
        e.Handled = true;
    } 
    else
    {
        base.OnKeyDown(e);
    }
}
```

This way, you don't have to muck with the logic that shows the context menu on right-click.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Show()` method of the `ContextMenuStrip` allows you to provide a control on which it is shows as well as the location.

For instance in example below:

```
this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(button1, new Point(50, 50));
```

It will display the menu 50 pixels to the right and below the `button1`. And when specifying only the location:

```
this.contextMenuStrip1.Show(new Point(50, 50));
```

The menu is displayed in the position relative to the main form.

Comment: If I go the route of `Show()` I now have to manually hook both the `OnMouseUp` and `OnKeyDown` protected methods in order to intercept the user actions that trigger the menu. This opens me up to bugs -- I'd rather be able to say "if the menu was opened by keyboard, show it here"

Comment: In that case you probably have to override standard context menu strip and implement your own version of opening on key down - with a fixed position relative to a parent form.

Comment: I tested this out, and got it working with the default logic in the mouse case, and with `Show()` logic in the keyboard case. I will mark your answer, and then edit my question to show what the code ended up looking like.